I don´t add flutter to PATH
I beginner on Linux and I'm installing flutter in my Debian. The installation work, and I added to PATH, but the flutter command don't work.
The flutter package is at /home/anthony/development/flutter and I edited ~/.profile file how user root using export PATH="/home/anthony/development/flutter/bin:$PATH".
I thing that ~/.profile can't access the home, but I'm not sure.
I expect run the flutter doctor command.

tried . ~/.profile? more https://linuxize.com/post/bash-source-command/

Don't forget to prefix that with source @pskink

@pskink yes. I'm added the export PATH in ~/.profile

@FrankvanPuffelen i prefixed that with . (dot) ;-)

TIL (from the link too): "source and . (a period) are the same command"

@Anthony you added it in ~/.profile but most likely you did not sourced that file - so your changes did not apply in the current environment - either do source ~/.profile or . ~/.profile

Or logout and log back in, then it will be done automatically.

@pskink, i did this, but dont work : (

so what does echo $PATH show now? does it really have /home/anthony/development/flutter/bin?

@pskink the $PATH show /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

your flutter bin not saved yet to your $PATH, my way is to edit (in case you use bash the default shell for debian) edit the .bashrc by nano ~/.bashrc (you can change nano to vim or editor you use. Then at the bottom of the file add export PATH="/home/anthony/development/flutter/bin:$PATH", then save and restart terminal. (or logout and login to make sure the .bashrc already implemented.

It's work, but only root user. How normal user don't work
